# Redirect & consecutive POST request

Tags: php, post, redirect

I'm submitting a login form via:

```
$loginRequest = array(
                      'Username' => 'myUsername'
                      'Password' => 'myPassword'
);
$request = new HTTP_Request2($url, HTTP_REQUEST2::METHOD_POST);
$request->addPostParameter($loginRequest);
$response = $request->send();
```

The POST is successful and the output of $`response` is

```
</body>
<a id="refresh_url" href="/homepage">Loading...</a>
</body>
```

which (at least when manually logging through Chrome) redirects to another form with input

```
 <FORM name="autologin" method=POST action="https://homepage/AccountSettings">
 <input type="hidden" name="Z" value="0,0">
```

I'm not sure how to have PHP programmatically handle `refresh_url` and redirect to `/homepage` Also, how can I force PHP to submit this last form as well?

**EDIT**

There's also the following meta tag on the intermediate page

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=/vdesk/?langchar=en.iso-8859-1&amp;ui_translation=off&amp;gbrowsertype=">
```

Comment: That `<a>` won't cause a redirect. Are you sure there's no `<meta http-equiv="refresh">` tag in the result?

Comment: @Barmar I just checked. Yes there is, and I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do two things:

1) You want to go to the "next page." You can do this by looking for the meta refresh tag, and going to the target URL. You can get the URL from the contents of the meta refresh tag using a simple regular expression.

2) You want the next page to recognize that you have logged in. If this is a normal webapp, then you need to parse the Set-Cookie: headers that come in the original request, and turn them into Cookie: headers that you send along when you request the next page.

If you want to further follow links from the next page, you may also need to look for cross-site request forgery security tokens, that many web application frameworks put in the page data, and you have to provide back when posting, to defend against certain browser-based session hijacking attacks.

Note that not every site will have a meta refresh after logging in -- credentials for HTTP applications are not standardized in reality (as the web authorization headers are not generally used.) If you want to do a whole lot with a bunch of different sites, you'd better hope those sites have programmatic APIs of some sort, rather than resorting to HTTP web page scraping.

Comment: What does the PHP method to retrieve response cookies look like? Also, would I be sending ALL cookies to the next page?

Comment: You have to get the response headers from the $response object, and look for the Set-Cookie header. And, yes, you want to send all the cookies to the next page. You can send multiple cookies in a single Cookie header. I highly recommend reading the HTTP protocol specification for more information: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html It really is required reading for someone doing web engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't redirect and then POST.

See the [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern: that's how you should try to implement a login page.

Comment: He's not implementing a login page, he's trying to automate logging into the page, and the page redirects to an "update profile" page when you login.

Comment: Sorry I misread the question... by the way it shouldn't be possible to POST the form after a redirect

Comment: He wants to submit in a **new** form, the one that's on the page that he's redirected to.

Comment: @Barmar that's correct. I'm automating page login. How is it possible to submit a new form after submitting a previous one?

Comment: @MarkKennedy You do it the same way you submitted the first form. Construct the parameters and send a request to the new form's action URL.

Comment: I can only make the submit the second form once I've logged in, correct? Since the second form is account settings, I can't jump to there without having logged in. Is it possible to do consecutive POST?

Answer (score 0):

If you are capturing the post (username/password) then you would normally load the page using PHP like this:

```
header("Location: /homepage");
```

But from your example you seem to be confusing client-side and server-side for processing the login.  Take a look a the simple code here:
http://php.thedemosite.co.uk/logincode.php
it should help.